# React native components causes error when consumed from another package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, npm, expo

I built a library of react native components and I used this [template](https://github.com/storybookjs/react-native) so I can integrate storybook and I also used [nativewind](https://www.nativewind.dev/) which is basically a react-native implementation of tailwind. My components look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export interface ComponentProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  bold?: boolean;
}

const MyComponent = ({
  children,
  bold = false,
}: ComponentProps) => {    
  return (
    <Text
      className={`${bold && 'font-bold'} text-gray-800`}
    >
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Then I have an `index.ts` for each component for exporting:

```
export { default, ComponentProps } from './MyComponent';
```

Then to compile my project I just run the `tsc` command and this is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "es7",
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "types": ["react", "react-dom", "react-native"],
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "app.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

I then added a github workflow so that whenever I create a new release it generates a github package:

```
name: Node.js Package

on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile

  publish-gpr:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
          registry-url: https://npm.pkg.github.com/
          scope: '@username'
      - run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - run: yarn build
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

The package is created successfully and I'm able to import and use my components:

```
import MyComponent from '@username/package-name/dist/MyComponent';

 // Another component from a different project
 return (
   <View className="w-36">
     <MyComponent>test</MyComponent>
   </View>
 );
```

However I'm getting all these errors and warnings when using these components:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call.

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')`

Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 1379 and callID 689 for module <unknown>. Args: '[19]

Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 1385 and callID 692 for module <unknown>. Args: '[20]'

Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method JSTimers.callTimers(). Module has not been registered as callable. Bridgeless Mode: false. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 0): .
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

ExceptionsManager.js:153 Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 1860 and callID 930 for module <unknown>. Args: '[true]'
```

I don't think I'm violating any hook call, maybe because of the "early initialization error"? If anyone can help that would be great, thanks.

Here are the dependencies for my components library:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "expo": "^49.0.7",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  }
```

Here are the dependencies for my other project:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@username/my-components-library": "0.1.12", // my package
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.19.0",
    "expo": "~47.0.9",
    "expo-application": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.42.1",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1300.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.9",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2"
  }
```

They both use React v18 and running the command `yarn why react` I get this output:

```
=> Found "react@18.1.0"
info Has been hoisted to "react"
info This module exists because it's specified in "dependencies".
info Disk size without dependencies: "388KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "420KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "448KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 2
=> Found "@username/my-components-library#react@18.2.0"
info This module exists because "@username/my-components-library" depends on it.
info Disk size without dependencies: "388KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "420KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "448KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 2
```

Comment: I'm just taking a guess: are you running multiple versions of React? This may depend on how your package was built and/or installed. Could you share the package.json of both the dependent and dependency? I see you're using Yarn so the output of `yarn why react` in the dependent might also be useful.

Comment: @Wing I updated my post and aded both dependencies.

Comment: Your components package depends on 18.2.0 while your project depends on 18.1.0. Could you share the output of running `yarn why react` inside the directory for the project? This will also help confirm two versions of React are being used. Libraries should typically include React as a peer dependency (not a direct dependency).

Comment: @Wing I updated my post, also how can I configure my library peer dependencies? instead of direct dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

Your project and library both specify a number of (direct) dependencies that are the same. For example, React, which I think is the dependency that's causing the error is specified as a dependency of your library with version 18.2.0 and a dependency of your project at version 18.1.0. When you build the library, React at version 18.2.0 is bundled with it. When you build the project, React at version 18.1.0 is bundled along with your library which already includes React at version 18.2.0. This means two versions of React get bundled in the build for the project with some parts of your code calling React 18.1.0 and other parts calling 18.2.0.

## Solution

You should specify dependencies duplicated across both packages as a peer and development dependency of your library. A peer dependency tells the package manager the package has a dependency but it should be installed *alongside* the package (hence peer) and not as a *child* as a normal dependency would. It also needs to be specified as a development dependency so that, in development, import references can be followed by things like your IDE. Using React as the example again, inside the `package.json` for the component library you need to remove React from the dependencies and add:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "x.y.z"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "x.y.z"
  }
```

You should specify version ranges that are flexible enough to work with other dependencies that also have the respective dependencies as their peer dependencies.

## Further reading

- [`npm` documentation on peer dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies)
- [Node.js blog post on peer dependencies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies)